# When will this multinomial coefficient be the largest?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Consider the multinomial coefficient $\left( \begin{array}{ccc} & 
>  2015 & \\n& n& 2015-2n \end{array}\right)$. For what value of $n$ will this multinomial
>   coefficient be the largest?

For a binomial coefficient, it is easy as it is a unimodal sequence and we can simply check the one (or two terms) in the middle of the sequence and we are done.

For a multinomial coefficient, however, I cannot do so. So, in what way should I argue for this? I hope that hints can be provided, but not the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not too different from the binomial coefficient proof. Consider the fact that it's value is invariant under permutations of the bottom numbers. You can view this as the constrained optimization problem: Maximize ${2015\choose a,b,c}$ subject to $a+b+c=2015$ and $a=b$

Comment: If you consider $a,b,c$ subject to $a+b+c=2015$, you're allowing for multinomials where $a\neq b\neq c$ which don't fall in the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Fixed.

Comment: @StellaBiderman : i somehow get the sense that in order to get the largest value, the three numbers $n$, $n$ and $2015-2n$ should be close to each other. But how should I argue for this formally?

Comment: @LeeKM Wow it's been a while, but this just popped up so I figured I'd respond. The way you prove that is by taking a derivative, setting it equal to zero, and solving. This problem is solvable using Lagrange Multipliers.

Answer (score 1):

To maximize the expression consider its algebraic form: $\frac{2015!}{n!\times n!\times(2015-2n)!}$. The numerator is fixed so to maximize it you want to minimize the denominator.

If you compare denominator with $n=k$ to next term with $n=k+1$ we see:

$$\frac{(k+1)!(k+1)!(2013-2k)!}{k!\,k!\,(2015-2k)!}$$

$$=\frac{(k+1)^2}{(2015-2k)(2014-2k)}$$

We want to consider denominators which are decreasing in value so the ratio of denominators needs to be less than 1 so solving:

$$\frac{(k+1)^2}{(2015-2k)(2014-2k)}<1$$

$$(k+1)^2<(2015-2k)(2014-2k)$$

$$k^2+2k+1<4k^2-8058k+4058210$$

$$0<3k^2-8060k+4058209$$

$$0<k^2-\frac{8060}{3}k+\frac{4058209}{3}$$

$$0<\left(k-\frac{4030}{3}\right)^2-\frac{4066273}{9}$$

$$k>\frac{4030+\sqrt{4066270}}{3},\,k<\frac{4030-\sqrt{4066273}}{3}$$

We'd expect the best when we only just satisfy the inequality so around $n=672$. Checking nearby numbers we find that $n=672$ is best.

Comment: Your solution is correct, I made a mistake expanding $(2015-2k)(2014-2k)$ in my solution... as this one is more complete as well I will delete my one instead of editing it.

Comment: I did find a minor mistake in my answer thanks to yours so you should have left it.